# .NET 461: OverflowException. Array dimensions exceeded supported range

Tags: .net, azure

I got a .NET function setup in two different environments (azure and local computer).

Executing it with same input arguments gives different results.
It succeeds on local computer but encounters error (OverflowException. Array dimensions exceeded supported range) on azure station.

Is it the environment or improper code a more likely cause?
If it is the former then what environment settings should one pay attention to?

Code that converts docx to pdf using Syncfusion 21.2.3

```
        [Function("ConvertDocxToPdf")]
        public HttpResponseData ConvertDocxToPdf([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            //Gets the input Word document as stream from request
            Stream stream = req.Body;

            //Loads an existing Word document
            WordDocument document = new WordDocument(stream);

            document.Background.Type = BackgroundType.NoBackground;
            document.ChartToImageConverter = new Syncfusion.OfficeChartToImageConverter.ChartToImageConverter();

            document.AcceptChanges();

            //Creates an instance of the DocToPDFConverter
            DocToPDFConverter converter = new DocToPDFConverter();

            converter.Settings = new DocToPDFConverterSettings()
            {
                EmbedFonts = true,
                RecreateNestedMetafile = true
            };

            //Converts Word document into PDF document
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = converter.ConvertToPDF(document);
            //Releases the resources occupied by DocToPDFConverter instance
            converter.Dispose();
            //Closes the Word document
            document.Close();

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            //Saves the PDF file 
            pdfDocument.Save(memoryStream);
            //Closes the PDF document
            pdfDocument.Close();

            //Reset the memory stream position
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            //Create the response to return
            
            HttpResponseData response = HttpResponseData.CreateResponse(req);
            response.Body = memoryStream;
            return response;
        }
```

Comment: Share the code which you used.

Comment: please share your code which you have deployed to Azure App Service.

Comment: This is C#? Please tag your questions appropriately if you want them to receive exposure to the correct audience.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the error is caused by the differences in the environment.

- Check the version of .NET framework installed in the local and the version of.NET framework used in Azure.
- Also check the version of Syncfusion used in both environments.
- And there are chances of the error is caused by the code itself. Check the size of the Word document.

> The error message shows that the array dimensions exceeded the supported range, which might be caused by a large document.

By splitting the input document into smaller chunks and process them separately also fixes the issue.

Able to convert local and azure successfully.

[image]

[image]

I used the syncefusion NuGets

[image]

For more information refer to [Syncfusion Blog](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/converting-word-docs-to-pdfs.aspx) and [MSDoc.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-dotnet-troubleshoot)